# Can Changelings be detected?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

If Zerg spawns a changeling inside your base, will having detection stop these annoying buggers from scouting your entire base?

Basically:Does Detection have an affect on Changelings. If so, what?

Comment: Sieged tanks have a good chance to kill them as they fire as soon as the changling drops, before it can morph. The downside is that if they drop a changling into a pack of SCVs, the siege tanks will do splash damage.

Comment: I suppose that would be true indeed.

Comment: There are mainly two ways Zerg will try to get a Changeling into your lines: Dropping them in the back of your base, or during an engagement. Both are easy to spot. In the first case, you should know that there was not <unit> of yours up there, and in the second, the Changeling will be set to follow one of your units, in which case moving the army around will quickly reveal him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After reading online this is what I found. (Basically no, detection has no influence on a Changeling.

> "Once disguised, the Changeling takes on the enemy's own color and will no longer be automatically attacked by the enemy's units, allowing it to infiltrate enemy territory unsuspected. Changelings cannot be discerned as impostors by any form of detection, nor will the secondary effects of EMP Round reveal their true allegiance. Likewise, a Sensor Tower's Radar ability will not identify the Changeling as hostile after it has morphed. However, if the opponent selects the Changeling, they will be unable to give it orders (since it is not theirs) and the word "Changeling" will appear in place of the unit type that it appears to be."
>   Source: [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Changeling)

Comment: Basically what @Nick122 said. The only way to realize you have a changling in your base: is to realize you have a changling in your base. Look for zealot / ling / marine acting all weird. Or did you not make any zealots ? why do you have a zealot then ? :P *edit: * oh I see you answered the question yourself >.<

Comment: Yeah, haha and I know. I was just wondering if detection helped. I have no problem finding a changeling ;)